# Product page goes into infinite loop after reindexing

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite, reindex, enterprise-1.13, flat-catalog

Every time I reindex using command line:

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

And try to load the product page, it goes into infinite redirect loop. 
For example in firefox, the browser results as:
[image]

But all the other pages: Homepage, Product listing(category) page etc. just works fine.

But one strange thing is, when you go through each category in backend to resave it and try to re-load the product page, it works fine.

I am trying to debug this strange issue. One thing I have noticed in product listing (category page) is: body class is empty for css selector:
`categorypath`-[empty] `category`-[empty]
After resaving that category, then only body class shows the proper selector value for `categorypath`- & `category`-

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? Any idea/suggestions on the fixings?

**Note**: I am using Magento EE 1.13 & flat catalog is turned on. And we have updated the category & product url_key attribute from global to store view (to have different urls for different stores):

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET is_global=0 WHERE attribute_id IN (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code IN('url_key'))
```

[Edit]
After debugging, it is found that catalog_category_flat_store_[store_id] table's url_key field is NULL after reindexing. Also, catalog_category_entity_varchar has no entries for url_key for those categories for which product are not loading.

Comment: I haven't experienced this issue firsthand, although I have seen wacky reindexing issues with EE 1.13. If you were to take a clean copy of EE1.13.1.0 with your database. Using the default Enterprise theme, attempt to reindex via SSH. I wonder if you will still see the issue. If you don't see the issue anymore, you can point it to being a code issue, and if you do still see the issue you can point it to being a database issue. I would also suggest toggling flat catalog on and off (which I prefer to be turned off with EE1.13 due to issues).

Comment: @kab8609 fyi, flat catalog is turned on. May be i will try to toggle this and check further. Thanks

Comment: @kab8609 Seems to be an issue with Flat Catalog. When I turned off the Flat Catalog then I can see the css selector in body class and the product page is loading fine. After that I turned it on and the same weird issue.

Comment: Other notes: the category(product listing) page has url_key empty when reindexed. And I think the issue is somehow related with this empty url_key which gets populated when the related category is saved.

Comment: What specific version are you on in 1.13?

Comment: @kab8609 Magento EE 1.13.1.0

Comment: When you run the reindex process. You get 0 errors, correct? Do you have any of the Magento patches for EE1.13 installed, and if so, which ones?

Comment: Yeah. There is no errors while reindexing. We have Flat catalog turned on and imported the products via Advanced Profile. I am not sure about the patches used but at least I know that we upgraded from 1.12

Comment: One more thing to note: We changed the url_key settings from global to store view for both category & products.

Comment: You may want to look into EE 1.14.x codebase, as there is a mention of a related issue fixed: "Switching stores when viewing a product with store-scoped URL keys works as expected." http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-later-release-notes#ee114-1400fixes

Comment: You should add all the ideas as answers. If they don't help MagePsycho, they might help the next lost souls :)